# Special Characters in string literals

Tags: python, string, set

I am making a set in Python to house all the symbols on my keyboard, but obviously a few pose some issues. Is there a way to get them all in there without encountering problems?

Here is my set:

```
symbols = {`,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,-,+,=,{,[,},},|,\,:,;,",',<,,,>,.,?,/}
```

To get around commenting out most of it, since in Python `#` is to comment, I enclosed everything like so:

```
symbols = {'`','~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','-','+','=','{','[','}','}','|','\',':',';','"',''','<',',','>','.','?','/'}
```

Which works for that character, but now I can already see an issue when I come across the `'` and `\`. Is there a better way to make this set?

Comment: OK, so you need to store these characters as strings. Your first line doesn't fail because of the comment character, but because you can't just type a bunch of text that's not in a string and expect it to work. For the rest, you need to understand how to 'escape' special characters in a string, and maybe figure out whether you want a **list** or a **set** to store the strings in.

Comment: Note that I fixed your terminology.  What you have there is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set), not an array.  In fact, Python does not have a built-in array type (unless you are using [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array)).  Instead, we use [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can fix the backslash by escaping it and `'` can be fixed by putting it in double quotes:

```
symbols = {..., '\\', ... "'", ...}
```

But typing all this out is pretty tedious.  Why not just use [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) instead:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> set(punctuation)
{'~', ':', "'", '+', '[', '\\', '@', '^', '{', '%', '(', '-', '"', '*', '|', ',', '&', '<', '`', '}', '.', '_', '=', ']', '!', '>', ';', '?', '#', '$', ')', '/'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

[user2555451's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28056873/2827971) is spot on, but just as an observation on how to get these into Python efficiently - the first part of your question - try this:

```
symbols = set(r"""`~!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}}|\:;"'<,>.?/""")
```

That:

1. Wraps the string in three quotes to simplify handling the single or double quote issue
2. Puts an `r` in front of the string to handle the escape character
3. `set` converts the string to a set

The initial string was missing the close square bracket, just as an aside. Using a simple set operator:

```
>>> symbols - set(string.punctuation)
{']'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `"\\"` which outputs `"\"` in the python terminal, if you try to use `"\"` then python will throw you an error so, instead of `"\"` use `"\\"` which will print the same value that is: `"\"`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would rather put them all in triple quotes, like this. It would ignore any special characters:

```
`''' `,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,-,+,=,{,[,},},|,\,:,;,",',<,,,>,.,?,/'''`
```

Comment: you can also use a raw string